# Scale in band description of Google Earth Image

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am processing OpenLandMap images. In this, one image collection is [soil organic carbon content](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/OpenLandMap_SOL_SOL_ORGANIC-CARBON_USDA-6A1C_M_v02#description). In the description of this collection, it is written that,

> Soil organic carbon content in x 5 g / kg

I have doubt about this `x 5`. Also, the images have a scale of 5.

What does this mean? **To get the actual organic carbon content of the soil should I multiple the pixel values with 5 or divide those with 5, or should I use these values as it is?** Are the `x 5` in the description and 5 in the scale imply the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of units (Soil organic carbon content in x 5 g/kg) are provided to significantly reduce file size of global soil organic carbon content maps. So, for converting to %, you only have to divide by 2. Explanation can be obtained from [here](https://zenodo.org/record/2525553). However, you can deduce this factor as follows.

5 g of OC in 1 kg of soil = 5 g of OC in 1000 g of soil

```
5 g of OC in 1000 g of soil
f g of OC in 100 g of soil
```

f = 5 x 100 / 1000 = 500/1000 = 1/2

So, factor (f) is 1/2 (0.5). You can divide by 2 or multiply by 0.5.

As you can observe in following [example](https://code.earthengine.google.com/?scriptPath=Examples%3ADatasets%2FOpenLandMap_SOL_SOL_ORGANIC-CARBON_USDA-6A1C_M_v02), values obtained for point -80.7408, 25.9836 (by using Inspector Tab) are always expressed as integer numbers. If you want them in percentages (floating point), you have to divide by 2.

[image]